# Disable a Single JS Script in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-tools

I have a page that loads a number of JS libraries from a CDN (Including jQuery and jQuery UI). I am testing a local script, and I want to check if the script will run properly if I disable some specific libraries. Is there a way to use Chrome Dev Tools to disable one or more of the JS libraries I'm loading?

For example, let's say I load the following:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Then, say I have a script on the site:

```
<script>...some script that runs when an element is clicked...</script>
```

I want to test and see if my local script will run if I disable one or both of the libraries. How do I use Chrome Dev Tools to do this and test?

Comment: You could create a rule in an ad-blocker addon, like Adblock Plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Charles web proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to re-route the cdn files so they load from your local machine. I'm not sure if this is possible with dev-tools alone.

Why don't you comment out the scripts so they don't load? That would be the simplest solution. You can run the site locally, correct?

Comment: I guess the answer to my question is 'no', which you provided, so you should get credit for the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the award! Would be nice if it was built-in to dev tools, for sure.